# why python cv2.drawContours() just draw the first contours?

Tags: python-2.7

I am having trouble filling a mask using cv2.drawContours, I dont know what could it be, or how to fix it.

I have a list with three elements's sublists [coordX,coordY, contour], so for every pair of coordinates, there is an if/else decision, each one with this stament: cv2.drawContours(mask,[l1[0][2]],0,c1[cla],-1)

[l1[0][2]]: contour, like array([[[437, 497]],[[436, 498]],[[439, 498]],       [[438, 497]]])

c1[cla]: tuple, like (25,250,138)

The script runs well without errors, but the resulting image is almost black, just having 4 green pixels.

Any suggestion or advice?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found what was the problem. I was passing the same contour to every step ([l1[0][2]]), so I need to change to operate with index, like [l1[i][2]]).

Sorry for that mistake and for your patience.

Have a good day, Jaime